# XPS Stream write to printer

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, xps

I am doing a raw write to a printer queue and for some reason on some of the printers specifically EPSON TM20II the printed document is actual raw content of XPS data.

Here is the chunk of code i use

```
 using (var TEMP_STREAM = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ConvertToXps(RECEIPT_DOC, TEMP_STREAM);
            using (var theJob = printQueue.AddJob())
            {
                using (var printStream = theJob.JobStream)
                {
                    printStream.Write(TEMP_STREAM.ToArray(), 0, (int)TEMP_STREAM.Length);
                }
            }
        }
```

Am i missing some configuration or there any checks needs to be made to ensure that printer can actually print XPS as raw data?

Comment: Is the printer you selected configured for PCL os PS?  You may be using the wrong print queue.  You may need to install both the PCL and PS print driver for you code to work.

Comment: Ok will check that out thanks!